# POSTGIS ST_Intersects returns contained polygons but not enclosing polygons

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a PostgreSQL table called `parks` in a database with PostGIS extensions which has a column named `perimeter` with Data type geography.

If I issue a query with a where clause like:

```
WHERE ST_Intersects(
  parks.perimeter,
  ST_GeogFromText('POLYGON((-122.31755953233409 47.61300937889849, ...))')
)
```

I see results where parks partially overlap the query polygon and parks that are entirely contained within the query polygon bit I do NOT see a park that completely contains my query polygon.

The [documentation](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Intersects.html) for ST_Intersects says:

> ST_Intersects — Returns TRUE if the Geometries/Geography "spatially intersect in 2D" - (share any portion of space)

By this definition I should see a result if `parks.perimeter` encloses my query polygon.

I could solve this with a second `ST_Contains` but that would slow down my time critical query and should be unnecessary.

Does anyone have an explanation why I am seeing this behavior and what I can do to fix it without a second clause?

Thanks.

Comment: What geometry type is `perimeter`? (i.e. Polygon, LineString, etc.)

Comment: ST_intersect should return true if a geometry (or geography) is completely contained in polygon. Post a complete example of data, where the record is contained in the polygon, but st_intersects return false: `SELECT ST_astext(parks.perimeter) WHERE ...`,

Comment: Mike, it's a Geography POLYGON added with an INSERT statement with a value created by : ST_GeogFromText('POLYGON(("...